# How to check if a ttf file contains a certain character?

Tags: command-line, fonts, unicode, ubuntu-font-family, .ttf

Using the command line, how can I check if a `*.ttf` file contains a certain character?

*I want to know if the font-file `Ubuntu-R.ttf` contains the `U+2007` (FIGURE SPACE) character.*

Comment: There is a small python script that does that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458696/finding-out-what-characters-a-font-supports).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hb-shape /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf `echo -ne "\u2007"`
```

returns:

```
[space=0+231]
```

so the character is defined